# C++ VTable implementation with multi-parent polymorphic hierarchies

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, vtable

If I have

A <- B (where both are polymorphic)

there are two levels of indirection when calling a function on B. Firstly a look up to determine what type of A object and then a lookup to find the function amongst all of B's.

Now if I had:

A <- B <-C (and all are polymorphic classes)

does this mean when I call a function on C it has to go through four levels of indirection (two for B and two for A)?

Comment: When you derive from a type the compiler has to know the complete type (including virtual functions) anyway so the compiler can easily bake the everything into the vtable. Then for any inheritance level: var.vtbl[func_idx]()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is always just a look-up in the vtable and a call of the resulting function. The depth of the inheritance tree doesn't make a difference. When multiple inheritance is involved (i.e., a class with multiple bases) it may be necessary to also adjust the pointer which becomes the `this` pointer.